# Grouping nodes by same values and summing

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to group `pi:PD` by `pi:Date` and `pi:Code` and sum their `pi:Amt` however, my for-each-group code is not working. This is my XML.

```
<pi:PEE xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
<pi:PG>
    <pi:HDR>
        <pi:Version>23</pi:Version>
    </pi:HDR>
    <pi:EMP>
        <pi:EAD>
            <pi:Code>1D</pi:Code>
            <pi:Date>2017-05-08</pi:Date>
            <pi:Amt>20.72</pi:Amt>
        </pi:EAD>
        <pi:PD>
            <pi:Code>SDF</pi:Code>
            <pi:Date>2021-02-19</pi:Date>
            <pi:Amt>40</pi:Amt>
        </pi:PD>
        <pi:PD>
            <pi:Code>SDB</pi:Code>
            <pi:Date>2021-02-26</pi:Date>
            <pi:Amt>2</pi:Amt>
        </pi:PD>
        <pi:PD>
            <pi:Code>SDB</pi:Code>
            <pi:Date>2021-02-26</pi:Date>
            <pi:Amt>30</pi:Amt>
        </pi:PD>
        <pi:AI>
            <pi:EDI>2020-05-01</pi:EDI>
        </pi:AI>
    </pi:EMP>
    <pi:EMP>
        ...
    </pi:EMP>
</pi:PG></pi:PEE>
```

And this is my XSLT. I want to know what is missing or wrong and what can I use instead to correct. Thank you!

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pi:EMP">
    <xsl:if test="pi:EAD or pi:PD">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pi:AI"/>

<xsl:template match="pi:PD">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="concat(pi:Date,pi:Code)">
        <pi:PD>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <pi:Code><xsl:value-of select="pi:Code"/></pi:Code>
            <pi:Date><xsl:value-of select="pi:Date"/></pi:Date>
            <pi:Amt><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/pi:Amt)"/></pi:Amt>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </pi:PD>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go up to the parent level and run your grouping needs where you can combine the `pi:EMP` and `pi:PD` templates as shown below. The `xsl:if` is handled with empty template that removes `pi:AI`. Finally, the inner `xsl:for-each>` is not necessary. Run below with empty template and identity transform template.

```xml
<xsl:template match="pi:EMP">
   <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:copy-of select="pi:EAD"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="pi:PD" group-by="concat(pi:Date,pi:Code)"> 
         <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="pi:Code|pi:Date"/>
            <pi:Amt><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/pi:Amt)"/></pi:Amt> 
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:for-each-group> 
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```xml
<pi:PEE xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
   <pi:PG>
      <pi:HDR>
         <pi:Version>23</pi:Version>
      </pi:HDR>
      <pi:EMP>
         <pi:EAD> 
            <pi:Code>1D</pi:Code> 
            <pi:Date>2017-05-08</pi:Date> 
            <pi:Amt>20.72</pi:Amt> 
         </pi:EAD>
         <pi:PD>
            <pi:Code>SDF</pi:Code>
            <pi:Date>2021-02-19</pi:Date>
            <pi:Amt>40</pi:Amt>
         </pi:PD>
         <pi:PD>
            <pi:Code>SDB</pi:Code>
            <pi:Date>2021-02-26</pi:Date>
            <pi:Amt>32</pi:Amt>
         </pi:PD>
      </pi:EMP>
   </pi:PG>
</pi:PEE>
```